# How to Pass PKCS12 password into openssl conversion module?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, encryption, openssl

**script.sh**

```
certKey=$(openssl rand -hex 70)

openssl pkcs12 -export -out fullchain.p12 --passin pass:$certKey -inkey .../privkey.pem -in .../fullchain.pem
```

I when calling this script the certKey is not passed in, and system asks me for the pkcs12 password. But I am clearly trying to pass $certKey in.

[openssl Documention](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/openssl/pkcs12.1ssl.en.html)

"-passin arg
The PKCS#12 file (i.e. input file) password source. For more information about the format of arg see the PASS PHRASE ARGUMENTS section in openssl(1)."

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It is not acceptable here to add SOLVED to the title or to edit a solution into the question. If an answer someone posted has helped you, you can accept that [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and it lets everyone know you've found a solution. If you've solved the problem on your own and want to share it, do so by writing an answer in the space provided for that purpose below. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @KenWhite ok great thanks, I wont do it again

Answer (score 1):

Should be -passout

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out fullchain.p12 -passout pass:$certKey -inkey .../privkey.pem -in .../fullchain.pem
```